# how to create ssl certificate yourself using .net?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, security

googled a bit but could not find anything quickly? is it possible to create a live suitable ssl certificate with .net 4.0? MakeCert.exe only creates certs for testing purposes? any other ways to do this? I would like to create a 1536 bit RSA key?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create certificates in code, then BouncyCastle or [PKIBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) package of our SecureBlackbox would do the job. However, unless you are a Certificate Authority or you have a CA certificate with the private key, certificates that you create would have limited usability. You can build your own certificate hierarchy but without being trusted (and trust if what CAs give you) browsers and operating systems won't trust your certificates by default.